# Input Voltage Threshold of Raspberry pi

Tags: sensor, pi-gpio

I am a beginner in physical computing and accidentally gave my Pi 5volts and my Rasbperry Pi shut down (I'm really worried it's becoming more damaged overtime if I keep on doing this), because I was using a module sensor meant for arduino that delivers 5 volts as an input. I'm trying to use a voltage divider so that only 3 volts will enter one of the Pi's GPIO pins. I understand the schematics and the drawing, but I'm having a hard time picturing what this looks like on a breadboard. Could someone please send me pic of what a voltage divider looks like? I would appreciate that! Also, just to be clear, IS it okay to ground 5V into a ground pin in the Raspberry Pi or will this cause it to be damaged as well? The sensor has a Vcc, Grnd, AO (analogue input), and DO input as its integrated pins. For reasons I won't disclose, I won't be able to acquire a ADC converter, and plus I don't need to detect any kind of "real world values" just the instance when the sensor immediately detects something its supposed to detect.  Also I am only able to use a 10K and 330 ohms resistor....

Comment: [Here](https://fastapi.metacpan.org/source/STEVEB/RPi-HCSR04-0.02/docs/hcsr04.png) is a breadboard layout example of a voltage divider to drop the 5v output from the Echo pin to the Pi GPIO pin to 3.3v.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're supplying voltage via GPIO, be careful.  There is no voltage regulation performed on the GPIO pins.  [This article](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-do-i-power-my-raspberry-pi) indicates:

> "If an incorrect voltage is applied, or a current spike occurs on the
>   line you can permanently damage your Raspberry Pi. At best, you’ll
>   “burn out” some or all of the GPIO pins, at worst you can fry your Pi!
>   So be careful."

Comment: Wow.   Downvotes without an explanation?   Did I miss something from the OP's question?